# jQuery showing empty string on input text?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form like this

```
<form action="">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var Name = jQuery('#name').val();
    jQuery('#name').blur(function() {
      console.log(Name);
    });
  });
</script>
```

but here when I am entering any values in the input text field it is showing error like 
`(an empty string)`. So can someone tell me what is the wrong here? How to solve this?

Comment: You didn't close the id of your input, and use no empty `action` tags.

Comment: Yes, for the closing of the ID, but empty action is fine.  It just assumes the current url if it doesn't get passed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
var Name = jQuery('#name').val();
```

is a one time operation, setting the value of `Name` to the value of the input when that code executes. It will **not** magically update the value of `Name` when the value of that element changes (why do so many people get the impression that it would?). You'll need to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#name').blur(function () {
        console.log(this.value);
    });
});
```

I've cut out the now pointless `Name` variable, and just used the element reference (`this`) directly to get its value property rather than using jQuery functions.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" id="name />
```

should be

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TdLH2/

Comment: i think your answer is not correct, the OP may have had a typing mistake, please correct the answer, before someone down votes or flags

Comment: You are right, it had trouble accessing the Name variable outside the blur function.

Answer (score 2):

Name variable should be set inside onblur handler:

```
jQuery('#name').blur(function () {
    var Name = jQuery(this).val(); //or this.value
    console.log(Name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form action="">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function()
   {
    jQuery('#name').blur(function () {
    var Name = jQuery("#name").val();
    jQuery("#name").blur(function() 
     {
      console.log(Name);
    });
   });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to console.log whatever is typed into the box, you can do:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#name').keyup(function() {
        var Name = jQuery('#name').val();
        console.log(Name);
    });
  });
</script>
```

At the moment, you're getting the value of `#name` on page load, which would be `""`, an empty string. As nothing has been entered.