# Input field wouldn't get the updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field with id Email and im getting the value of this field to update my object. However when i try to edit it again without a refresh and try to send it via Ajax, email field becomes empty. I get this field by using              $("#Email").val() and I tried using .attr("value") as well however this gets the old value of the field not the new value.

My problem is similar to this "[jQuery showing empty string on input text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265601/jquery-showing-empty-string-on-input-text)" however, I can't use the solution there as I have to use the input box multiple times after updating.

Answer (score 2):

> However when i try to edit it again without a refresh and try to send it via Ajax, email field becomes empty.

Are you sure the page is not refreshing? The field can only become empty from either a refresh, or actual JavaScript code you have written/included that is causing the problem.

`$("#Email").val()` will read the value and will not blank it out.

`.attr("value")` will read what the value was when the page loaded, but not accounting for changes made by the user.

> My problem is similar to this "[jQuery showing empty string on input text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265601/jquery-showing-empty-string-on-input-text)" however, I can't use the solution there as I have to use the input box multiple times after updating.

Do you understand the reason for that solution? The problem there was that the value was captured to a variable `Name` too early. The solution was to move the call to `val()` to later. (after `blur` took effect, not before)

---

I hope these are helpful, but there's really not much more I could tell you without seeing your code.

I expect this question to be closed due to lack of details. When you post the new question, please try to fix one problem at a time (either "becomes empty", or "gets old value") and post enough details for a solution. (i.e. an SSCCE)

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your reply. I noticed that one of the problems were that my colleagues code was setting my variably to "". However, I'm still unable to fetch the input value without refreshing. I change the value on the input but when I inspect the element it still shows up as the old value. Ill post it here too if I find a solution. Thank you again for your time

Comment: Inspect Element is likely to use `getAttribute("value")` (used by jQuery `attr("value")`) which represents the original value when the HTML was loaded. This is different from the real-time editable value, which is accessed with `.value` (or in jQuery, `.val()`) If Inspect Element is looking at the attribute instead of the latest value, then you may not be able to rely on Inspect Element for this.

Comment: Yes you are right! I am using .val() to get the latest value. What I have is an edit row that i hide and show in order to edit and after edit is complete I set value to "" and hide the controller and send the data via Ajax. However when i want to edit again and enter a value, email is always empty string, and as you said the inspected element has the old value. What Im trying to do is to get the new added value